# Properties of finite group and their subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $a, b \in G$ such that $ab = ba$. Then the subgroup generated by $\langle a, b \rangle = \{ a^i b^j : \; 0 \leq i \leq |a| -1, \; 0 \leq j \leq |b| -1 \} $ is a subgroup of $G$. Define a map $\psi : \langle a, b \rangle \rightarrow \langle a \rangle \times \langle b \rangle$ by $a^i b^j \mapsto (a^i, b^j).$ If $b \in \langle a \rangle$, then $b = a^k$ for some $0 \leq k \leq |a| -1$. This mapping is not well defined because $\psi(ab) = \psi(aa^k) = (a^{k+1}) = (a, a^k)$ and   $\psi(ab) = \psi(a^2a^{k-1}) = (a^2, a^{k-1})$. If $a \notin \langle b \rangle$ and $b \notin \langle a \rangle$. This map gives us an isomorphism and $\langle a, b \rangle \cong  \langle a \rangle \times \langle b \rangle $.

I feel that  the arguement  which is given by me is properly right or not. Please look at this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\renewcommand{\phi}{\varphi}$$\newcommand{\Set}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}$$\newcommand{\Size}[1]{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}$$\newcommand{\Span}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}$If $\Span{a} \cap \Span{b} \ne \Set{1}$, then $$
\Size{\Span{a, b}}
=
\frac{\Size{a} \cdot \Size{b}}{\Size{\Span{a} \cap \Span{b}}}
< \Size{a} \cdot \Size{b} = \Size{\Span{a} \times \Span{b}},
$$ so will not have an isomorphism.

To get an isomorphism, you thus *have to* require $\Span{a} \cap \Span{b} = \Set{1}$, not just $a \notin \Span{b}$ and $b \notin \Span{a}$.

In any case, it is probably advisable to start with the homomorphism, that is always well-defined
\begin{align}
\phi : & \Span{a} \times \Span{b} \to \Span{a, b}\\
       & (a^{i}, b^{j}) \mapsto a^{i} b^{j}.
\end{align}
Its kernel is
$$
\ker(\phi) = \Set{(a^{i}, b^{j}) : a^{i} = b^{-j}}.
$$
So you see that $\ker(\phi)$ is trivial iff $\Span{a} \cap \Span{b} = \Set{1}$, and then the argument with orders shows that $\phi$ is an isomorphism.